# Replicate rows in a Pyspark Dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataframe:

```
id, test, date
1, A, 01/20/2020
1, B, 01/25/2020
2, A, 02/20/2020
2, B, 02/25/2020
2, C, 02/25/2020
```

Since the number of distinct tests is 3(A,B,C) I want a row for test C to be inserted for id 1 with date as "NA"

The resulting dataframe should be:

```
id, test, date
1, A, 01/20/2020
1, B, 01/25/2020
1, C, NA
2, A, 02/20/2020
2, B, 02/25/2020
2, C, 02/25/2020
```

Answer (score 2):

Example data

```
data = [
    ('1', 'A', '01/20/2020'),
    ('1', 'B', '01/25/2020'),
    ('2', 'A', '02/20/2020'),
    ('2', 'B', '02/25/2020'),
    ('2', 'C', '02/25/2020'),
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['id', 'test', 'date'])
```

Generate a cross table first

```
# Solution
uniq_ids = df.select('id').distinct().coalesce(1)
uniq_tests = df.select('test').distinct().coalesce(1)
skeleton = (
    uniq_ids.
        crossJoin(
            uniq_tests
        )
)
+---+----+
| id|test|
+---+----+
|  1|   B|
|  2|   B|
|  1|   C|
|  2|   C|
|  1|   A|
|  2|   A|
+---+----+
```

Then left-join to it

```
(
    skeleton.
        join(
            df,
            ['id', 'test'],
            'left'
        ).
        orderBy('id', 'test', 'date').
        show(truncate=False)
)
+---+----+----------+                                                           
|id |test|date      |
+---+----+----------+
|1  |A   |01/20/2020|
|1  |B   |01/25/2020|
|1  |C   |null      |
|2  |A   |02/20/2020|
|2  |B   |02/25/2020|
|2  |C   |02/25/2020|
+---+----+----------+
```

A recommendation with real data

- If you have lots of unique `id`s and unique `test`s, you may want to change how many partitions you `coalesce(N)`.

Answer (score 1):

For **`spark2.4+`**,a highly scalable way **`(without any join)`** would be to use **`groupBy`**, **`collect_list`** and **`array function`** /**`higher order functions`** to determine missing links, add those links and then **`explode.`**. It will work for any order of *missing* **`A,B or C.`**

```
#sampledataframe
#df.show()
#+---+----+----------+
#| id|test|      date|
#+---+----+----------+
#|  1|   A|01/20/2020|
#|  2|   A|02/20/2020|
#|  2|   B|02/25/2020|
#|  2|   C|02/25/2020|
#+---+----+----------+


from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.groupBy("id").agg(F.collect_list("test").alias("x"),F.collect_list("date").alias("col2"))\
                   .withColumn("zip", F.arrays_zip(F.col("x"),F.col("col2")))\
                   .withColumn("except", F.array_except(F.array(*(F.lit(x) for x in ['A','B','C'])),"x")).drop("x","col2")\
                   .withColumn("except", F.expr("""transform(except,x-> struct(x,'NA'))"""))\
                   .withColumn("zipped", F.explode(F.array_union("zip","except")))\
                   .select("id",F.col("zipped.x").alias("test"),F.col("zipped.col2").alias("date"))\
                   .show(truncate=False)

#+---+----+----------+
#|id |test|date      |
#+---+----+----------+
#|1  |A   |01/20/2020|
#|1  |B   |01/25/2020|
#|1  |C   |NA        |
#|2  |A   |02/20/2020|
#|2  |B   |02/25/2020|
#|2  |C   |02/25/2020|
#+---+----+----------+
```

**`Physical Plan for Join Solution:`**(as shown by @cPak)

```
== Physical Plan ==
Sort [id#1206L ASC NULLS FIRST, test#1207 ASC NULLS FIRST, date#1339 ASC NULLS FIRST], true, 0
+- Exchange rangepartitioning(id#1206L ASC NULLS FIRST, test#1207 ASC NULLS FIRST, date#1339 ASC NULLS FIRST, 200), [id=#1110]
   +- *(6) Project [id#1206L, test#1207, date#1339]
      +- SortMergeJoin [id#1206L, test#1207], [id#1337L, test#1338], LeftOuter
         :- Sort [id#1206L ASC NULLS FIRST, test#1207 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
         :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#1206L, test#1207, 200), [id=#1101]
         :     +- CartesianProduct
         :        :- Coalesce 1
         :        :  +- *(2) HashAggregate(keys=[id#1206L], functions=[])
         :        :     +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#1206L, 200), [id=#1089]
         :        :        +- *(1) HashAggregate(keys=[id#1206L], functions=[])
         :        :           +- *(1) Project [id#1206L]
         :        :              +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[id#1206L,test#1207,date#1208]
         :        +- Coalesce 1
         :           +- *(4) HashAggregate(keys=[test#1207], functions=[])
         :              +- Exchange hashpartitioning(test#1207, 200), [id=#1095]
         :                 +- *(3) HashAggregate(keys=[test#1207], functions=[])
         :                    +- *(3) Project [test#1207]
         :                       +- *(3) Scan ExistingRDD[id#1206L,test#1207,date#1208]
         +- Sort [id#1337L ASC NULLS FIRST, test#1338 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
            +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#1337L, test#1338, 200), [id=#1104]
               +- *(5) Filter (isnotnull(id#1337L) && isnotnull(test#1338))
                  +- *(5) Scan ExistingRDD[id#1337L,test#1338,date#1339]
```

**`Physical Plan for Non-Join solution(using array functions+explode)`**

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(2) Project [id#1206L, zipped#1400.x AS test#1405, zipped#1400.col2 AS date#1406]
+- *(2) Generate explode(array_union(zip#1380, except#1394)), [id#1206L], false, [zipped#1400]
   +- *(2) Project [id#1206L, arrays_zip(x#1374, col2#1376) AS zip#1380, transform(array_except([A,B,C], x#1374), lambdafunction(named_struct(x, lambda x#1395, col2, NA), lambda x#1395, false)) AS except#1394]
      +- ObjectHashAggregate(keys=[id#1206L], functions=[collect_list(test#1207, 0, 0), collect_list(date#1208, 0, 0)])
         +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#1206L, 200), [id=#1192]
            +- *(1) Project [id#1206L, date#1208, test#1207]
               +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[id#1206L,test#1207,date#1208]
```

*As we can see the join solution produces many data shuffle exchanges, and uses cartesian product(highly inefficent for bigdata). The data movement will be extremely high and highly taxing on any cluster. As compared to array function/explode solution, the data movement will be much lower and processing much faster.*